# 2 submit buttons

Tags: html

I have a webpage which has 2 submit buttons.

How do I `post` a value to another page based on the button clicked.

Lets say the 2 buttons on the form are `yes` and `no`.  If the `yes` button is clicked, I want to post the value `1`, if the no button is clicked, I want to post the value `0`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

It does not have to post `1` and `0`, it can post any value, as long as the page being posted to knows which option was selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" name="thisismysubmitbutton" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" name="thisismysubmitbutton" value="no" />
```

One displays and posts the value `yes`, the other displays and posts the value of `no`. Note that the `input` element needs to have a valid `name` attribute, else the `value` is not posted.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for: http://www.chami.com/tips/internet/042599i.html

Comment: Please add some more information into your answer: pages tend to disappear from time to time, and an answer containing *only* a link is not very useful anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer to the question pretty much does just that. I just didn't want to copy what was on that website anyway, but I see your point. Will remember this in my next answer.